# Linux numeric sort out of order

Tags: linux, sorting, csv

I have a 1800+ line csv file.  I wanted it sorted on the 8th column.  So I used sort.

```
sort  -t, -nk8 fefa.csv | cut -d, -f8
```

resulted in the following elided output

```
...
1431299970
1431301041
1431301050
1431291020   (???)
```

I did an examination of the file and it seemed that all the values were 10 chars.  So I did sort again but without the numeric flag:

```
sort  -t, -k8 fefa.csv | cut -d, -f8

...
1431301041
1431301050
1431301050
1431301089
```

This is the correct order.  On further examination the original file was already in the correct order.

My questions is: Why did the original sort (numeric) fail?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of a csv file that causes the problem? I tried, but I don't see any difference with or without -n if all the numbers have the same length.

Comment: On looking at the man page for sort I modified the original numeric sort to use the -nk8,8 for the key.  I assume at this point that the -nk8 which tells the sort to use column 8 to end of file and the computation of a number from that does something odd.